# Stock list view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I feel like using this many partial views where a view renders a partial that renders a partial is just digging a hole of poor design, so I'm looking for any suggestions or guidance as to if this is best/worst practice.  One of the reasons I don't like it is because it seems too easy to duplicate code across the different views to handle styling.  Here they are in order of nesting.

**The index view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<RESTDemo.Models.StockQuote>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Demo Stock Watch List</h2>

<fieldset>
<legend>StockQuote</legend>
<div id="controls">
    <input type="submit" name="Refresh" id="Refresh" value="Refresh"
           data-submit-action="refresh" data-submit-method="get"
           data-submit-url="@Url.Action("Refresh")" data-stock-target="#stockTable" />

    <input type="submit" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Clear List"
           data-submit-action="reset" data-submit-method="delete"
           data-submit-url="@Url.Action("Reset")" data-stock-target="#stockList" />

    <form id="addStock" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Add")" data-add-ajax="true" data-stock-target="#stockTable">
        <input type="search" name="symbol" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
</div>
</fieldset>
@Html.Partial("_stocks", Model)
```

**The _stocks view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<RESTDemo.Models.StockQuote>
<div id="stockList">
    <table id="stockTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Symbol</td>
            <td>Last Price</td>
            <td class="change">Change</td>
            <td class="change">Change Percent</td>
            <td>Volume</td>
            <td class="last-column"></td>
        </tr>
            @Html.Partial("stockList", Model)

</table>
</div>
```

**The stockList view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<RESTDemo.Models.StockQuote>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
string cssClass;
if (item.Change > 0)
{
    cssClass = "num-pos";
}
else if (item.Change < 0)
{
    cssClass = "num-neg";
}
else
{
    cssClass = "num-zero";
}


<tr class="data-row">
    <td class="stock-symbol">@item.Symbol</td>
    <td>@item.LastPrice</td>
    <td class="@cssClass">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Change)</td>
    <td class="@cssClass">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChangePercent)</td>
    <td>@item.Volume</td>
    <td class="last-column">
        <span class="delete-me" data-action="@Url.Action("Remove")" data-stock-method="delete"> </span>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

And finally the stock partial which is used as the response to an Ajax call to insert a single row into the table:

```
@model RESTDemo.Models.StockQuote

@{
string cssClass;

if (Model.Change > 0) {
    cssClass = "num-pos";
}
else if (Model.Change < 0) {
    cssClass = "num-neg";
}
else {
    cssClass = "num-zero";
}
}
<tr class="data-row">
<td class="stock-symbol">@Model.Symbol</td>
<td>@Model.LastPrice</td>
<td class="@cssClass">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Change)</td>
<td class="@cssClass">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ChangePercent)</td>
<td>@Model.Volume</td>
<td class="last-column">
    <span class="delete-me" data-action="@Url.Action("Remove")" data-stock-method="delete"> </span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I don't see anything you have done here as bad practice or poor design, that being said, I would probably not opt to nest as deeply.  In my thinking, breaking up the the view into sub views should be done for 2 possible reasons.

- Organization
- Reusibility

I am assuming that you don't intend to reuse these views elsewhere in the application, if that is the case, you are only gaining organization.  When that is the case, I would probably not put the list body into a separate view, but only the list elements.  In other words, break into a subview only when your bound context changes, IE, you are binding to a item instead of the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it definitely makes sense to consider what the model is bound to.  I am doing this more for learning, so this is a very limited scope application.  I think I initially split the list body off so an Ajax call to refresh the data wouldn't have to write the whole table, just the contents, but it really isn't that much data.